# What does the default trust policy in an AWS IAM role mean?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can you please explain what `ec2.amazonaws.com` means here? In what way can I now assume the role?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [Principal](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Principal) within an [Amazon IAM policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html) specifies *the user (IAM user, federated user, or assumed-role user), AWS account, AWS service, or other principal entity that is allowed or denied access to a resource*:

> You use the `Principal` element in the trust policies for IAM roles
>   and in resource-based policies—that is, in policies that you embed
>   directly in a resource. For example, you can embed such policies in an
>   Amazon S3 bucket, an Amazon Glacier vault, an Amazon SNS topic, an
>   Amazon SQS queue, or an AWS KMS encryption key.

For the policy at hand, the principal is the AWS service `ec2.amazonaws.com`, that is, this trust policy grants the [Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) service to assume *any* IAM role in your account (i.e., a `"Resource": "*"` statement is implied).

- you could further constrain the policy to only cover one or more specific roles, which would need to be explicated via a `Resource` statement like `"Resource": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID-WITHOUT-HYPHENS:role/ROLE-NAME"`
- this is most commonly seen/used in the context of [IAM Roles for Amazon EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html), where you are effectively [Using an IAM Role to Grant Permissions to Applications Running on Amazon EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html)

Comment: Nice answer. Still, I can't understand why my instance with current role A not able to assume role B, when the ec2 service is already specified here. Basically, what i am looking for is some way to inherit properties of one role into another, using assume role or some other way.

Comment: Yeah, according to the docs you can do role chaining, but so far I haven't figured out how to do this or found a good example of it. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: I solved it by using AWS STS with assumed role. Sadly, I didn't figure out the chaining and stopped looking.

Comment: (old, I know) Errrr... In a trust policy, you don't use resources, and this example doesn't grant the EC2 service permission to assume _any_ role. A trust policy is attached to a specific role and grants the EC2 service permission to assume _that_ role, and _only_ that role.